# Why are the libraries in Utils.py not loading?

Tags: python, import

I am having trouble identifying what causes this problem. Basically, I am working on a jupyter notebook that runs on a conda environment.
I have created a file "Myutils.py" which has some helper function for later use. the file is saved in the same folder as the notebook.
Giving that I have made the necessary imports in the notebook as well as in the Myutils file, I still got a name error:

In notebook:

first cell:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from MyUtils import *
%matplotlib inline
```

then:

```
img = cv2.imread('./yolov5/runs/detect/exp/crops/address/422.jpg')
plt.imshow(remove_noise(img))
```

produces this error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17892/550149434.py in <module>
      1 img = cv2.imread('./yolov5/runs/detect/exp/crops/address/422.jpg')
----> 2 plt.imshow(remove_noise(img))

~\Documents\Machine Learning\Projects\CIN OCR\MyUtils.py in remove_noise(image)
      5 def get_grayscale(image):
      6     return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
----> 7 
      8 # noise removal
      9 def remove_noise(image):

NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
```

And, in the Myutils.py, we have:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# get grayscale image
def get_grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: By doing `from Myutils import *` you are overriding the earlier `import cv2` - don't know if this is what is causing your bug, but it's worth avoiding `import *` unless you are certain there are no conflicts - see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: I tried removing the * and specifying the function to be used, but the same error appeared.

Comment: Actually, after restarting the whole process and by specifying the functions in the import code line, it worked! So, I guess the problem is indeed within the import * as you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: You can write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `from Myutils import *` you are overriding the earlier `import cv2`.

I don't know if this is what is causing your bug, but it's worth avoiding `import *` unless you are certain there are no conflicts - see e.g:

[Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)